# Computational Problem on Bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

Given a bipartite graph $G$ with vertex classes $A$ and $B$ and a constant $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k<|A|$ is the problem of finding ALL (not just verifying the existence of) subsets $S \subseteq A$ such that $|N(S)|=|S|-k$ solvable in polynomial time?

Comment: Could you provide some context (e.g., where does this problem come from), and what are your thoughts on this?

Comment: We can reduce the problem to the case $k=0$ by adding to $B$ $k$ vertices such that each of them is connected with all vertices from $A$.

Comment: Ahh yes an interesting idea that is true! So i guess can the $k=0$ case be solved efficiently?